# jQuery - Filling a form to make a nested JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I'm following [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592417/how-to-generate-nested-json-object-from-nested-list-with-javascript-jquery) where the user has an Html structure. From that one, user must obtain a particular nested JSON. The question has also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/X8J7J/) as you can see.

I want to make something similar. I'm trying to change that code where, instead of having static names, you can fill the names of html fields as in a form.

In the code I made a first change, in particular this line: `<ul><span class="board-title">Staff Retreat</span>` modified with this one: 
 `<ul><input type="text" name="firstname">` 
In addition, the .js script was changed from this line:

```
$(this).find('.board-title').text();
```

to that one:

```
$(this).find('#firstname').val();
```

So, I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3JuQ/) based from the first one with the possibility to set the first one field dynamically (instead of having "staff-retreat" name), but I get "undefined" on that value.

Comment: I’d love to help but your explanation is so confusing. Can you try to simplify it and break it down for us?

Comment: Ok, i'll try make something more clear :)

Comment: fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3JuQ/1/  `title = $(this).find('[name=firstname]').val();` and don't wrap in loader function in jsFiddle

Comment: Hope that now question is more clear, @A.Wolff, thanks for that hint!

Comment: You are getting id (firstname) in jquery, but in your html you are using name attribute (no id). So either add id in the html or use as A.Wolff's solution.